# Total angular momentum $j$ and the total magnetic quantum number $M$

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum, atomic-physics, quantum-spin, orbitals

I'm not sure if I am overcomplicating things with this question, but I have a question where we have a beryllium atom where its outermost electron is excited to the 3p orbital state. I have each quantum number for each electron in the electron config of 1s^2, 2s^1 and 3p^1, and used the equation $j=l+s$ for each electron, is it as simple as adding each $j$s together or am I missing something? As for the addition of magnetic quantum number, is it also just the additions of all the electrons $m_l$ value?

Comment: LS coupling should be used here, not j-j coupling